# inserting mutiple column values into single insert value?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

So I have this University assignment in which I have to create a trigger called bill_overdue. When a row that has status = overdue is inserted into table invoice, a row is inserted into another table called message.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AUTOINCREMENTMESSAGE
MINVALUE 100
START WITH 101
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10
;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BILL_OVERDUE
BEFORE INSERT ON INVOICE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.STATUS = 'Overdue')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MESSAGE (MESSAGENO,MESSAGEDATE,ORIGIN,MESSAGE)
VALUES (AUTOINCREMENTMESSAGE.nextval,SYSDATE,USER,:NEW.DATEISSUED,:NEW.INVOICENO,:NEW.CAMPAIGNTITLE);
END;
/
```

Now as you can see I want to add `:new.dateissued`, `:new.invoiceno` and `:new.campaigntitle` into a single field(`message`).Now I know that what I have done is wrong but I've tried adding parentheses around it etc and nothing seems to do what I want. How do I get this to work?  Is it possible to do what I want or have I got it completely wrong?

Comment: You are inserting six values into three columns. That won't work. You will have to combine three of the values into one using one of the concatenation methods given below (assuming it makes sense to concatenate them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [concatenation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php)

```
:new.dateissued || ', ' || :new.invoiceno || ', ' || :new.campaigntitle
```

Answer (score 3):

For Oracle you can also concatenate using the `CONCAT()` function and you can try

```
CONCAT(:NEW.DATEISSUED,:NEW.INVOICENO,:NEW.CAMPAIGNTITLE)
```

You may have to cast/convert some of those values though.